# Is there any IDE capable of Rename refactoring namespaces in PHP?

Tags: php, ide, namespaces, refactoring, rename

Do you know any PHP IDE capable of rename **classes and namespaces**, and refactor the code (all files) properly?

Answer (score 3):

Same as the suggestion made by @BetaRide. I use PHPStorm: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ and its probably one of the best IDE's I have used. Check it out

Comment: PhpStorm can move classes to different namespaces, but it cannot rename the namespace itself... So you have to move all your classes with the `refactor/move(F6)` one by one if I am right...

Comment: No, I am not :D I just checked, you can move and rename namespaces as well... By moving them, phpstorm creates or removes directories, so this works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Zend Studio?  It's not free, but it will refactor/rename across files in a project.

Comment: Yes I've tried it, but you can't rename (and refactor) namespaces. Netbeans doesn't support it either.

Comment: It's the same for PDT and PHPStorm. Actually I didn't find any tool doing this automatically.